# 画面検索条件のエクスポート、インポートをしたい

Tags: c#, asp.net

タイトルの件、asp.netで選択しているComboBoxの値やTextBoxの入力値、ラジオボタンの選択値、ListBoxの選択値などを保存ボタンをクリックすることでローカルのPCに検索条件としてファイル保存（エクスポート）したいです。
また、その保存したファイルをアップロード（インポート）して、画面に検索条件を再現したいです。

方法や参考ソース等ありましたらご教示下さい。
直感的には、XMLファイルでインポート、エクスポートするのが良いのかなと考えております。

Comment: 質問文に回答を書くのではなく、[自己回答し自己承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBに画面の検索条件を登録、呼び出しすることで実現できました。